# Storing data globally in Python

Tags: python, django

Django and Python newbie here. Ok, so I want to make a webpage where the user can enter a number between 1 and 10. Then, I want to display an image corresponding to that number. Each number is associated with an image filename, and these 10 pairs are stored in a list in a .txt file.

One way to retrieve the appropriate filename is to create a NumToImage model, which has an integer field and a string field, and store all 10 NumToImage objects in the SQL database. I could then retrieve the filename for any query number. However, this does not seem like such a great solution for storing a simple .txt file which I know is not going to change.

So, what is the way to do this in Python, without using a database? I am used to C++, where I would create an array of strings, one for each of the numbers, and load these from the .txt file when the application starts. This vector would then lie within a static object such that I can access it from anywhere in my application.

How can a similar thing be done in Python? I don't know how to instantiate a Python object and then enable it to be accessible from other Python scripts. The only way I can think of doing this is to pass the object instance as an argument for every single function that I call, which is just silly.

What's the standard solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: you don't need an object. you can have global references in your main server file (I would recommend you start with flask rather than django, though, it is quite simpler).

Answer (score 0):

The Python way is quite similar: you run code at the module level, and create objects in the module namespace that can be imported by other modules.

In your case it might look something like this:

myimage.py

```
imagemap = {}
# Now read the (image_num, image_path) pairs from the 
# file one line at a time and do:
#     imagemap[image_num] = image_path
```

views.py

```
from myimage import imagemap

def my_view(image_num)
    image_path = imagemap[image_num]
    # do something with image_path
```